# jenkins debugging of SCM

Tags: git, version-control, jenkins, polling

How can you debug and investigate why SCM polling is not working jenkins?  Clearly, there are easy ways to enable it , but I'm finding that it simply "stops" working sometimes, and although I can see the SCM logs which say polling hasnt happened recently, Im not sure where to start with investigating where the polling is actually occuring.

Answer (score 4):

Your jobs will have an SCM polling log, e.g. `http://jenkinshost/job/jobname//scmPollLog`, which will tell you if the execution of the SCM polling is having problems such as not being able to find the SCM client executable.

The Jenkins master log may also show errors - the location of this log depends on how you've installed Jenkins, so if you can't find it add a comment here and I'll try to help you out.

You should also double check the cron expression you're using in the SCM polling section of your Jenkins job, just to make sure it's really firing on the schedule you want.  You can test cron expressions with tools such as http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: My SCM log actually shows no problems.  that is very odd to me.  just FYI ive noticed that this coincided with a complete lack of any console logging, andbuilds halting .  any thoughts on how this all could coincide?  cloning the project to a new one seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: That is odd if that one project wasn't building or polling while other jobs were building.  Glad you got going again, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in [Jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24244) about polling issues.

It might be caused because Jenkins is in "shutdown mode". In this case the scm polling is skipped.